# Azure AD provisioning sends SCIM replace operation when adding user to group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, provisioning, scim

I have user and group provisioning set up for an enterprise application in Azure AD. I have a SCIM endpoint setup in my application to consume the SCIM requests from Azure AD. I added this feature flag to my tenant URL to ensure SCIM compliance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/application-provisioning-config-problem-scim-compatibility#flags-to-alter-the-scim-behavior

I have a group assigned to the enterprise application for provisioning to my application. When I add users to that group in Azure AD, I'm seeing two PATCH requests to the `Groups/:id` SCIM endpoint. The first is an add operation, which I expect because I'm adding this user as a member of the group:

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
    ],
    "Operations": [
        {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "members",
            "value": [
                {
                    "value": "directory_user_01F7SGPZHKVGHZMCRNHGJXW1E9"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The second PATCH request is a replace operation, which is unexpected as I'm not replacing all users in a group with the one member being added:

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
    ],
    "Operations": [
        {
            "op": "replace",
            "path": "members",
            "value": [
                {
                    "value": "directory_user_01F7SGPZHKVGHZMCRNHGJXW1E9"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The [SCIM protocol RFC outlines the difference between the add and replace operations in PATCH requests](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7644#section-3.5.2). If users are added as members of a group, there should only be an add operation, not a replace operation. Is there any way to configure Azure so it only sends add operations in this situation? Thanks!

Comment: Any findings here ? I am having same issue. SCIM is firing the Remove Operation for all the old members, when I add new member to the Group. Can't figure it out.